# How Can I append a XML node to Xml Document 's specific node?

Tags: c#, xml, appendto

I have a `XMLNode item` to be appended to the `XMLNode targetNode` of `XMLDocument docRss`

```
 XmlNode targetNode = docRss.SelectSingleNode("channel");
 targetNode .AppendChild(docRss.ImportNode(item, true));
```

**Exception**: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

**EDIT** I found that **targetNode is null but why?** as in the docRss.innerXml Show us that its present

*BEFORE THIS STATEMENT VALUE ARE:*

```
docRss.innerXml   = <?xml version=\"1.0\"?><rss version=\"2.0\"><channel><title>The federal Savings Bank News Feeds</title><link>https://www.thefederalsavingsbank.com</link><description>The federal Savings Bank News Feeds</description><language>en-us</language></channel></rss>

item.innerXml  = <title>Housing market improvement helps economy</title><link>https://www.thefederalsavingsbank.com/Advice</link><description>&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;According to The Associated Press, a strong housing report helped improve the stock market, showing that the housing market affects more than just one industry.&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;\r\n&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;The Dow increased by 5.22 points to close at 13,557, which marked the fourth straight day of gains, which is thought to be a result of the improving housing market.&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;\r\n&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;Time Magazine recently reported that a recovery for the housing market is also great news for large banks. The Department of Commerce announced that new residential construction projects increased by 15 percent in September in comparison to the prior month, and they also increased by 34.8 percent compared to last year.&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;\r\n&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;Housing starts are still down from the numbers that were seen before the recession, but the market is steadily improving every month.&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;\r\n&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;First-time home buyers who are interested in purchasing a home might look at now as the perfect time considering the low cost of mortgages and affordable rates that are offered. Those considering buying their first home should look into FHA loans considering they offer lower interest rates.&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;</description>
```

Comment: Did you mean to have that space after `"targetNode "`? It's likely that `targetNode` is null :-)

Comment: please check that line `XmlNode targetNode = docRss.SelectSingleNode("targetNode ");`. It can not find such node.

Comment: @dash no its a typo now corrected

Comment: yes ... I am doing it in a loop and for first time it will be null

Comment: Which one is null? Either the select of `targetNode` isn't working (and that's null) or `docRss.ImportNode(item, true)` is returning null. There's not quite enough code present to solve this, but, you should consider checking if `targetNode != null` before doing the `targetNode.AppendChild` if `targetNode` can be null, and you should also consider checking the value of `docRss.ImportNode` in the same way.

Comment: I Have updated the docRss innerXml Before The statement

Comment: Looks like `XmlDocument.ImportNode` never returns null so it is either `targetNode` or `item` are null.

Comment: any reason for not using LINQ2XML

Comment: M totally new to C#  and need to develop this ASAP.

Comment: I updated my Que Please look see if it helps

Comment: The document does not seem to contain any 'targetNode' Xml element.

Comment: it contain as its a `channel` element I updated my Que

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to manipulate an RSS feed.  Wouldn't a lot of your pain points be removed by using the members of the [System.ServiceModel.Syndication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357210.aspx) namespace?  SyndicationFeed and Rss20FeedFormatter, for example...

To add a node to a feed try this...

```
void RetargetFeed()
{
    string feedLocation = "http://example.com/rssfeed";

    // read original feed
    Rss20FeedFormatter rssformat = new Rss20FeedFormatter();
    rssformat.ReadFrom(XmlReader.Create(feedLocation));

    // create a list of items from the rogiinal
    List<SyndicationItem> items = new List<SyndicationItem>();
    items.AddRange(rssformat.Feed.Items);

    // add a new item to the end of the list
    items.Add(new SyndicationItem("Test Item", "This is the content for Test Item", new Uri("http://Contoso/ItemOne"), "TestItemID", DateTime.Now));

    // create a new Rss writer
    SyndicationFeed newFeed = new SyndicationFeed(items);
    var writeFormat = new Rss20FeedFormatter(newFeed);
    //and write the output to a file
    writeFormat.WriteTo(XmlWriter.Create("testoutputfile.xml"));
}
```

Comment: I am getting the xml from a third party source and using it for my website rss feeds if it can be done by `System.ServiceModel.Syndication` can you show me a example as m totally new to c#

Answer (score 1):

the  `targetNode` is null so i was selecting it wrong it must be  selected as

```
 XmlNode channel = docRss.SelectSingleNode("rss/channel");
```

Comment: You caught me mid sentence  :-)